# PHP Regular Expression to apply brackets markup as bold

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a project right now that is a shoutbox. Since I have disabled all HTML as people would most likely forget to close a tag ans screw up everything, I wanted to make a different form of adding some flair for people to use in their posts.

What I want to to is setup a regular expression in PHP to add tags around text. Here is an example of what I want to do...

If a person types "[Hello!] How is {everyone}?" it would display as such...
"**Hello!** How is *everyone*?"

The text in between the [ ] brackets would become bold and the text in between the { } brackets would be italics.

Does anyone know how to write a regular expression for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use Markdown, Textile, WikiText, or BBCode?

Comment: Using the such would require another framework implemented into the code. I figured that a simple regular expression would keep the code simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\[([^\]]*)\]~', '<b>\\1</b>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~{([^}]*)}~', '<i>\\1</i>', $str);
```

As seen on [codepad](http://codepad.org/W8tPpvvu).

That being said, I disapprove of creating yet another mark up language. Like BBCode, it's evil.

BBCode is a markup language invented by lazy programmers who didn't want to filter HTML the proper way. As a result, we now have a loose "standard" that's hard to implement. Filter your HTML the right way:

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: +1 for the sentiment. Reinventing the wheel is a waste of time.

Comment: You are very smart when it comes to regular expressions haha. Worked like a charm!!! Thank you very much for your help!